# Why does my UIVIew load offscreen?

Tags: iphone, uiview

When my application starts I execute this code:

```
LViewController *aLViewController = [[LViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.viewController = aLViewController;
[aLViewController release];  
[window addSubview:[viewController view]];
```

but the view always loads a little too high and is hidden behind the status bar. I've tried changing the simulated user elements in Interface Builder to include the status bar but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to account for the height of the status bar when you add the view to the window:

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
CGSize statusBarSize = statusBarFrame.size;
CGFloat statusBarHeight = statusBarSize.height;

LViewController *aLViewController = [[LViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.viewController = aLViewController;
[aLViewController release];  

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                       statusBarHeight,
                                       window.bounds.size.width,
                                       window.bounds.size.height - statusBarHeight);

[window addSubview:[viewController view]];
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks.  This fix seems a little forced. Am I adding the view the correct way?

Comment: Typically you’ll add view controllers to Apple’s classes, such as a navigation controller or a tab bar controller. Those classes perform some magic to get around the status bar, so if you do it yourself, you don’t get it.